# Emailing bold text from a Windows Phone

Tags: c#, vb.net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have written an application for the windows phone that allows a user to create an email based on a form they complete within the app using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks.EmailComposeTask. However i want certain elements of the email body to appear in bold. I have tried using HTML tags and encoding a string as HTML but it just appears as 'false' when the body is shown within the email application on the Windows Phone.

My question is, is there any method you can use to send bold text in an email from a windows phone?

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.aspx

Comment: Yeah the library isn't compatible with Windows Phone unfortunately